# Could not get page inside of the docker's container

Tags: docker

I create sample image that has installed nginx with port 80 and has index.html for presentation.

I run my container with this command

```
docker run -it -p 192.168.4.100:80:80 --expose 80 --name sample sample_img nginx
```

now I try to get index.html for test with this command

```
wget http://192.168.4.100/index.html OK
wget http://172.17.0.2/index.html OK
```

everything fine but when I try to download this page inside of container it doesn't work until I change the ip to container's ip.

```
docker exec -it sample bash
wget http://192.168.4.100/index.html NOK
wget http://172.17.0.2/index.html OK
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Could you share the nginx configuration for this server?

Comment: It does not related to nginx configuration however the nginx's configuration is really simple     server { listen       80; server_name  localhost; root /opt}

Comment: More specifically, is it listening on 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Can you access other IP addresses on your network from within the container (say a web server running on some 192.168.x.x machine)? If not, you might find this helpful - https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/articles/networking/#communication-between-containers-and-the-wider-world